# Reading .domain cookie from subdomain

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to add a link on an invisionfree.com forum that passes the user id to the target of the link. eg. example.com/index.php?userid=17

The user id is in a cookie set by the forum with domain .invisionfree.com and path /forumname

I'm trying to read it with code running at z8.invisionfree.com/forumname

According to various articles and posts I've read, this should be fine. The cookie's domain starts with a '.' so it should be readable by any subdomain. It's not working though. If I write out the whole document.cookie, it only contains cookies set by z8.invisionfree.com. 
Does anyone know why?

Comment: Can you post an example of the Javascript you are using to read the cookies?

Comment: Initially this:
`function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}`

but when that returned 'undefined' for the cookie I was requesting, I simply wrote out the whole of document.cookie, and saw that none of the parent domain cookies were there.

Comment: If you look at the cookies from within the browser, do they appear there? It sounds like the cookies may not be writing properly.

Comment: Yeah they appear in the browser, that's how I know they have the domain .invisionfree.com.  I can see the user id, session id, and password hash, then there are some others to do with ads. They are written by the forum itself, not by my code, so I assume they must be working. The session id must be.

Comment: Do either of the sites use SSL? If the domain cookies are secure they won't be visible to non-SSL connections.